# Transform the type of a thrust vector

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

I am somewhat new to CUDA and thrust and I am currently struggeling with the following problem:

I have 2 structs carrying data.

```
struct S1 {
    unsigned long A, B, C;
}

struct S2 {
    double A, B, C;
}
```

At the start of the program I have a vector of the first struct and I want to use the GPU as well as a special functor to transform the vector of `S1` to a vector of `S2`. The result will have the same size as the input only with elements of a different type.

I am currently using this setup:

```
struct Functor {
    Functor() {}

    __host__ __ device__ S2 operator() (const S1& s1) {
        // perform some operation on S1 to convert it so S2
        // here I just copy the values
        return S2{s1.A, s1.B, s1.C};
    }
}

void main() {
    std::vector<S1> input;
    // fill the 'input' vector

    // move the input to a device vector
    thrust::device_vector<S1> input_d(input);
    // empty vector for struct S2
    thrust::device_vector<S2> output_d(input.size());

    thrust::transform(input_d.begin(), input_d.end(), output_d.begin(), output_d.end(), Functor());

    return 0;
}
```

The functor `Functor` is responsible for converting `S1` to `S2` (simplified in this case).

This code results in a compiler error since the `operator()` needs 2 arguments while I only want to have one input. Looking around the web I did not find a solution that applies to my problem.

Comment: You need to look at the documentation for `thrust::transform` a bit more carefully. Your diagnosis of the situation is completely wrong -- https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations_gacbd546527729f24f27dc44e34a5b8f73.html

Comment: @talonmies Yeah I see, thank you. But downvoting the question is not really a nice move. I misread something - the question is still valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As already pointed out in the comments I misread the documentation (see [here](https://thrust.github.io/doc/group__transformations_gacbd546527729f24f27dc44e34a5b8f73.html)). The solution is to use a unary functor and another way of calling the `thrust::transform`.

```
// this functor converts values of S1 to S1 by multiplying them with .5
// in the actual scenario this method does perform much more useful operations
struct Functor : public thrust::unary_function<S1, S2> {
    Functor() {}

    __host__ __device__ S2 operator() (const S1& s1) const {
        // very basic operations on the values of s1
        double a = s1.A * .5;
        double b = s1.B * .5;
        double c = s1.C * .5;
        return S2{a, b, c};
    }
}
```

The transform is then called as:

```
thrust::host_vector<S1> tmp;
// fill the tmp vector with S1 instances...

// move the host vector to the device
thrust::device_vector<S1> input_d;
input_d = tmp; 

// initializing the output with the same size as the input
thrust::device_vector<S2> output_d(tmp.size()); 

// calling the functor on all elements of the input and store them in the output
thrust::transform(input_d.begin(), input_d.end(), output_d.begin(), Functor());
```

**Edit:** Added some more code parts so it is actually working code.

Comment: No. The transform call is still wrong, and the functor doesn't do what your question implied you want. When I directed you to the documentation for the API, I wasn't only meaning the number of arguments, but also the template arguments of the function call.

Comment: @talonmies This does exactly what I specified and I have this code compiling and running just fine. Taking in a vector of S1, performing a operation on each element and storing this data in a vector of S2 elements.

Comment: Really? So you pass Functor, which is a *type*, to the transform call? And you have a functor method which returns an *uninitialized S2 instance*  somehow performs long to double conversion of the input data from an array of S1, even though it doesn't use the input data at all? I'm impressed

Comment: @talonmies I edited the code to more accurately reflect what I am doing. I did leave some parts out first because I thought it would be clear what exactly is going on. I hope you now see what I tried to achieve and that it works this way :)

Comment: The whole point of of this question and answer is to leave a usable trail for the next person with a similar problem, not just help you. So a sloppy question with an incomplete answer doesn't help further the goal of [SO], even if it helped you. So thanks for editing your answer to be more useful for future visitors